# change state of parent component without passing down

Tags: reactjs

render my parent component without passing down function in  props

I have some components like this

```
<MainComponent>
<Component1>
<Component2>
<Component3>

</Component3>
</Component2>
</Component1>
</MainComponent>
```

I want change state of  MainComponent inside Component3 without passing down props

Comment: why do you want to trigger a re-render of a parent component when nothing has changed to it ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli my parent component get some data from API I want to get that data again or change the state of parent component

Comment: `I want re-render MainComponent inside Component3`, so you want `<Component3><MainComponent/></Component3>`?

Comment: @HMR question edited, thank you

Comment: You may also want to use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context)

Comment: @JosephD. can you write a sample code for solving my problem, please

Comment: `without passing down props` you can create a container for Component3 that gets it's values from [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) or a state manager that connects to react like [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a state management framework **Redux**

> check how you can do this https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Redux will allow you to manage state between components without passing it in the props.

Comment: Redux doesn't do that, it's [react-redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux) that allows that. Redux only provides a way to create the store.